# Pdo Transaction does not roll back when while DELETE did not execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I am building am app that should execute multiple queries that involve insert, delete and update commands. There is no syntax error but I discovered that the delete command did not delete entry but the insert command inserted row and the action did not rollback. If the delete action did not happen, insert and others should be cancelled is the desired result.

---

```
<?
try {  
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
 $D = 2;
 $Dn = 3;

$dumpi = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `dumpi` .... SELECT .... FROM .... ");
$dumpi->execute();

$matchi = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `marchi` WHERE `id`=....");
$matchi->execute();

$usri = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `status`='0' WHERE `id`='$Dn' ");
$usri->execute();

$donati = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `dnsn` SET `status`='d' WHERE `id`='$D' ");
$donati->execute();

$donatidel = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `dnsn` SET `status`='d',`deleted_by`='m' WHERE `dn`='$Dn' AND `status`='1' ");
$donatidel->execute();

 $navwal = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wlt` SET `status`='0' WHERE `user`='$Dn'");
$navwal->execute();   

   $navwalt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wlt` SET `status`='0' WHERE `dn`='$Dn' ");
 $navwalt->execute(); 
 // dont let te $D and Dn confuse you, its not the one causing any error

$pdo->commit();

 // echo 'it works';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
$pdo->rollBack();
echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
 ?>
```

---

The code ended here...
my connection to Db is of this script here...(just added for ref. php7)

```
$pdoOptions = array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true);
 try {
 $pdo = new PDO(
"mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, //DSN
MYSQL_USER, //Username
MYSQL_PASSWORD, //Password
$pdoOptions //Options
);} catch (Exception $e) {
 // design this well to make sense
 die(
// conmment out in launch
$e->getMessage())


);
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you get any errors while executing any delete? If not, then there is no point in rolling back anything. 2. Using prepared statements this way is pointless, your code is still vulnerable to sql injection attacks and will be slower and consumes more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if a query do not find any data, **it is not an error.**

If it's important for you that the delete query should necessarily find the the record to delete, then you have to verify that manually and than throw an exception.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `marchi` WHERE `id`=?");
$stmt->execute([....]);
if (!$stmt->rowCount())
{
    throw new Exception("Delete didn't find a record")
}
```

And then catch Exception, not PDOException.

Note that for some reason you aren't using prepared statements while you should

Comment: Note that for some reason you aren't using prepared statements while you should : I DO NOT UNDERSTAND-- and also why should I not catch PDOException.